# (Android) hacking server by a simple socket

Tags: java, android, security, sockets

I have written an Android game. Now, I want to connect the marks of the players.

The code below is the client side program, which send their names, countries and marks to the server. Basically, I use ':' to separate the information.

However, hackers can know my server ip and port by decompiling .apk file. Then, they can create a basic java application to access my server. They could send me "hacker:badserver:123456789". Finally, the top mark becomes "123456789".

Is it more secure method to connect user's data?

```
Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
out.writeUTF("Hacker:HK:3910");
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security issues. Check http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Of course, check their help center before you assume this question (in its current form) is appropriate there.

Answer (score 2):

Hackers do not need the APK to ascertain your server's IP. They could simply use a proxy tool such as Fiddler or packet sniffer.

During my brief stint as a game developer (working on the network multiplayer features), you learn to just assume that cheaters and hackers have the source code to your game.  Then you design your protocols around that assumption.

So how do you guard your server from being hacked by a rogue client or from cheating?  You really can't, but here's some things that make it extremely hard.

1. Require the user to "log in" (name/password) from the game before allowing it to post anything to your server. If you catch someone cheating, ban their account from playing the game by disallowing them to login. Use a "ticket" or auth token in the header of each HTTP request for the server to validate. If you ban someone, it will be too annoying for them to get a new account to try again.
2. HTTPS instead of HTTP. Technically a hacker could beat this by simply changing his rogue client to post with HTTPS as well. He could reverse engineer the protocol by debugging your APK. But now you've made it so much harder for him to discover what the protocol is to begin with. With HTTPS, the hacker can't use an easy tool such as Fiddler to observe the network traffic.
3. Be wary of debug spew in release builds. Make sure your "Log" statements related to anything protocol wise are in debug builds only, never release builds.
4. Obfuscate everything and use something like HMAC to "sign" every message with a key. This technically isn't security, but will make it A LOT harder for anyone who breaks the encryption to continue.  Something like the following:

Example
code:

```
name = BASE64("Hacker");
messagetype = ROT13("HK");
score = 3910;
tosend = name + ":" + messagetype + ":" + Integer.ToString(score ^ 0xAAAAAAAA) + ":";
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
mac.init(Your_Secret_Key);
byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());
tosend += Encoding.EncodeBase64(rawHmac);
```

Where "Your_Secrey_Key" is encoded somewhere in your source code, and only decrypted at runtime.

The above will generate a string resembling the following:

```
SGFja2Vy:UX:AAAAA5EC:blahblahxyxunreadable
```

The corresponding server code will decode the message and validate with the secret key before accepting.

Is this perfect security?  No.

Should I build an ecommerce solution with these techniques?  Definitely not.

Do these techniques ward off 99% of the casual hacker that might be tempted to do cheat?  Absolutely.

Does it beat the most determined of hackers that are out to win the high score at all costs? Maybe not. But the "effort to reward" ratio goes way up. It may not be worth their time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another good idea will be to use the user password as part of your secret key.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman - good idea. Also injecting additional noise such as server generated cookies and timestamps into the hashed string to block replay attacks from occurring.